# Procedure for Asking a Question about a Extremely Controversial Topic

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There is a question I want to ask, but it is about an **extremely** controversial position in sexual ethics. I think there is a technical error in the logic one prominent philosopher uses to support this position, but I am afraid people will think I am trying to post a rant in disguise. Whether the position is true or not is irrelevant to my question; I am asking if specifically this argument that supports the position is flawed. How do I make it clear that I am not trying to offend anyone or push my own view onto others?

To make matters worse, the position is about a **extremely** NSFW topic. There is simply no possible way to research it without feeling the need to delete your browsing history afterwards. Even the Wikipedia article on this topic has 2 NSFW pictures right at the top. Is there some type of 'content warning' tag or feature I am suppose to use?

Comment: The mere asking of 'a question about an extremely controversial topic' might cause offence  - depends on its content - but more important than this is that the controversial nature of the topic is likely to attract answers that are just statements of personal opinion or, let's face it, prejudice. The site shuns such statements and rightly so. Further than this, it is hard to know what advice to offer since you give no indication of what the topic is or of what kind of matter (political, sexual ...) it is concerned with.

Comment: I would easily best $20 that if I ask my question someone will get banned for posting prejudice and offensive content. However, I do not believe that I should be held responsible if someone reacts with prejudice to what I say that itself is not prejudice. If the moderators this site disagree with me on this, then I will respect their decision and refrain from asking my question.

Comment: Is the subject matter essential to your question about their logic?  If not, would it be constructive to post a paraphrase?